# HTML CSS Image with paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I have some issues with image and text align. Trying to align image right text, but last one can't do this. Can you help me with this problem, please?

[image: gif]

```
.rows {
    background-color: #00a3cc;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
}

<div class="rows">
    <img src="img/mustang.jpg">
    <h3 class="class">#3 - Ford Mustang 1969</h3>
    <p class="class">The Ford Mustang...</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: try `float: right;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After observing the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8j7N.gif) which you have provided, we can see that **within the border of your #2 item, there is the #3 item**.
Also it seems that the #3 item is **respecting all the applied css** styling.
Hence only one probable case it seems to be that you may have placed #3 item's code within the #2 item's `<p>` Paragraph tag.

Presumably, from the limited code sample, I can say your current code might look like this:

```html
<div class="rows">
    <img src="img/car.jpg">
    <h3 class="class">#2 - Some Car Name, YYYY</h3>
    <p class="class">The paragraph starting....
//p tag and div tag never ends but item #3 exists inside item #2
    <div class="rows">
    <img src="img/mustang.jpg">
    <h3 class="class">#3 - Ford Mustang 1969</h3>
    <p class="class">The Ford Mustang...</p>
    </div> ...</p>
</div>
```

Whereas it should have been like:

```html
<div class="rows">
    <img src="img/car.jpg">
    <h3 class="class">#2 - Some Car Name, YYYY</h3>
    <p class="class">The paragraph starting ...</p>
</div>

<div class="rows">
    <img src="img/mustang.jpg">
    <h3 class="class">#3 - Ford Mustang 1969</h3>
    <p class="class">The Ford Mustang ...</p>
</div>
```

Hopefully this solves your query.

Comment: Thank you very much, but my code is a bit different. Every <div> in my code has <div></div>. So that's problem... All of them close, but nothing happens. <div class="rows">
  <img src="img/charger.jpg">
  <h3 class="class">#1 - Dodge Charger 1969</h3>
  <p class="class">The Dodge Charger is a model of automobile marketed by Dodge in various forms over seven generations between 1966 and today. The first Charger was a show car in 1964. A 1965 Charger II concept car had a remarkable resemblance to the 1966 production version.</p>
 </div>

Comment: oh, i fixed my problem when i deleted display:flex. Thank you